# How do you add a raster layer ontop of another raster map in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, merge, raster, tmap

I've created a base map as seen in the document provided. In addition to this I've also made a combined raster file with Fs values that I wish to overlay over the basemap.

I was wondering how I can overlay one on top of the other. Both have the same spatial coordinates.

Do i need to merge the raw data or can i simply plot one ontop of the other.

```
library(raster)
library(exactextractr)
library(mapview)
library(tmap)
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)
theme_set(theme_bw())
library(ggspatial)
library(rnaturalearth)
library(rnaturalearthdata)
library(rgdal)
library(classInt)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(basemaps)
library(mapedit)
library(terra)
library(tidyterra)
library(dplyr)
library(scales)
library(geodata)
library(showtext)
library(maptools)
library(sp)
library(rgeos)
library(GISTools)

indir <-'C:/Assessment2'

rast <- raster('C:/Assessment2/Coweeta_slope.tif')


shplist <- list.files(indir, pattern = '*.shp',all.files = TRUE, full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)



x <- lapply(shplist, shapefile)

m <- do.call(rbind, x)




m$slope <- exact_extract(rast, m, 'max')

spatial.variables <- as.data.frame(t(rbind(m$cohesion, m$soil_depth, m$soil_dens, m$hydro_cons, m$slope, m$frict_ang, m$slope)))



m$Fs = round(as.numeric(as.numeric(m$cohesion)/(as.numeric(m$soil_depth)*as.numeric(m$soil_dens)*9.81))+((as.numeric(m$hydro_cons)*cos(as.numeric(m$slope))*tan(as.numeric(m$frict_ang)))/sin(as.numeric(m$slope))),digits =2)



{r include=FALSE}
tmap_mode("view")


tm_shape(m) +
  tm_polygons(col = "Fs")


# Preparting workspace
m
setwd('C:/Assessment2')
getwd()
dir.create('mydir')

# Converting polygons to .shp file
writeOGR(obj=m, dsn='mydir', layer= 'mshp', driver='ESRI Shapefile')

# Raster conversion process
Fshp <- readOGR(dsn='C:/Assessment2/mydir', layer='mshp')

# Creating raster skeleton, setting coordinate system and projection
Ftemp <- raster(ncols=8, nrows=15,xmn=275309 ,xmx=276835, ymn=3880601, ymx=3881923, crs='+proj=utm +zone=17 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs')
  
# Populating Ftemp
Frast1 <- rasterize(Fshp, Ftemp, getcover=TRUE, progress = 'text')  

Frast1 

Frast <- as(Frast1, "SpatRaster")
  

r_init <- 'C:/Assessment2/DEM.tif'
map <- terra::rast(r_init)

names(map) <- "alt"

r_init
map

autoplot(map) +
  theme_minimal()


## Creating hillshade effect

slope <- terrain(map, 'slope', unit = 'radians')
aspect <- terrain(map, 'aspect', unit = 'radians')
hill <- shade(slope, aspect, 30, 270)

# Normalising names
names(hill) <- 'shades'

# Hillshading, but we need a palette
pal_greys <- hcl.colors(1000, 'Grays')

ggplot() +
  geom_spatraster(data = hill) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = pal_greys, na.value = NA)



# Using a vector of colors
index <- hill %>%
  mutate(index_col = rescale(shades, to = c(1, length(pal_greys)))) %>%
  mutate(index_col = round(index_col)) %>%
  pull(index_col)

# Getting columns
vector_cols <- pal_greys[index]

# Avoiding resampling and not using aes
hill_plot <- ggplot() +
  geom_spatraster(
    data = hill, fill = vector_cols, maxcell = Inf,
    alpha = 1
  )

hill_plot


# Hypso gradient
grad_hypso <- hypso.colors2(10, 'dem_poster')

autoplot(map) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = grad_hypso, na.value = NA)

{r}

map_limits <- minmax(map) %>% as.vector()

# Rounded to lower and upper 500
map_limits <- c(floor(map_limits[1] / 500), ceiling(map_limits[2] / 500)) * 500

# Making min value to 0.
map_limits <- pmax(map_limits, 0)

# Comparing
minmax(map) %>% as.vector()

map_limits

{r}

base_plot <- hill_plot +
  # Avoiding resampling with maxcell
  geom_spatraster(data = map, maxcell = Inf) +
  scale_fill_hypso_tint_c(
    limits = map_limits,
    palette = 'dem_poster',
    alpha = 0.4,
    labels = label_comma(),
    # For the legend I use custom breaks
    breaks = c(
      seq(0, 500, 100),
      seq(750, 1500, 250),
      2000
    )
  ) + ggplot(Frast,
     add = TRUE, 
     alpha = .5)

base_plot

# Loading in custom fonts
myload_fonts <- function(fontname, family,
                         fontdir = tempdir()) {
  fontname_url <- utils::URLencode(fontname)
  fontzip <- tempfile(fileext = '.zip')
  download.file(paste0('https://fonts.google.com/download?family=', fontname_url),
    fontzip,
    quiet = TRUE,
    mode = 'wb'
  )
  unzip(fontzip,
    exdir = fontdir,
    junkpaths = TRUE
  )

  # Loading fonts
  paths <- list(
    regular = 'Regular.ttf',
    bold = 'Bold.ttf',
    italic = 'Italic.ttf',
    bolditalic = 'BoldItalic.ttf'
  )


  namefile <- gsub(' ', '', fontname)
  paths_end <- file.path(
    fontdir,
    paste(namefile, paths, sep = '-')
  )


  names(paths_end) <- names(paths)

  sysfonts::font_add(family,
    regular = paths_end['regular'],
    bold = paths_end['bold'],
    italic = paths_end['italic'],
    bolditalic = paths_end['bolditalic']
  )

  return(invisible())
}


{r}

# Theming
showtext::showtext_auto()

# Adjusting text size
base_text_size <- 10

for1_plot <- base_plot +
  # Changing guide
  guides(fill = guide_legend(
    title = 'm',
    direction = 'horizontal',
    nrow = 1,
    keywidth = 1,
    keyheight = 0.3,
    label.position = 'bottom',
    title.position = 'right',
    override.aes = list(alpha = 1)
  )) +
  labs(
    title = 'Coweeta Experimental Catchment',
    subtitle = 'Factors of Safety for Landslide Scars',
    caption = paste0(
      'Produced by Aleksander Zarebski \n Topographic Data: Shuttle Radar Topography Mission (SRTM)\n Landslide Variables: Coweeta Experimental Catchment Observatory'
    )
  ) +
  theme_minimal(base_family = 'sans') +
  theme(
    plot.background = element_rect('grey97', colour = NA),
    plot.caption = element_text(size = base_text_size - 6),
    plot.title = element_text(face = 'bold', size = base_text_size),
    plot.subtitle = element_text(
      margin = margin(b = 10),
      size = base_text_size - 2
    ),
    axis.text = element_text(size = base_text_size - 4),
    legend.position = 'bottom',
    legend.title = element_text(size = base_text_size - 6),
    legend.text = element_text(size = base_text_size - 6),
    legend.key = element_rect('grey50'),
    legend.spacing.x = unit(0, 'pt')
  )

for1_plot
```

Comment: Can you please provide a *minimal, self-contained, and reproducible* example? For example, only use packages that are essential for the question at hand.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a *minimal* example with base plot.

```
library(terra)
f <- system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra")
x <- rast(f) * 10
y <- rast(f)
y[40:60,] <- NA
plot(x, col=rainbow(50))
plot(y, add=TRUE, legend=FALSE)
```

If you want something else then perhaps you can first simplify your example code; it is much too long and complex for a simple question like this.